# Android Testing Support Library does not seems to be visible

Tags: android, mockito, android-testing, android-espresso

If Espresso, Mockito, Junit all are part of Android Testing Support Library then why does these doesn't they are automatically imported. 
As we need to explicitly add them into our project by specifying in the build.gradle file

Comment: Probably because not everyone writes Espresso tests or uses Mokito (thought they should). You have a point with JUnit, and while there are alternatives to that too, none of them are worth the time. For those who use the Espresso Test Recorder, most of these dependencies are automatically added (minus mockito, to their detriment). The easiest way to minimize mobile app footprint is to require developers to opt in to additional libraries, not include them by default just because it's convenient to the developer.

Comment: Just to add to the great comment above, Espresso is an extremely heavyweight library with many transitive dependencies and can contribute significantly to `androidTestCompile` build times.